# Questions containing my "favorite tags" are barely distinguishable

Tags: feature-request, design

I liked the fact that in MO v1, any question which contained one of my list of favorite tags was noticably highlighted (a brown-orange color, if I remember correctly).

In the new version, such questions are still highlighted -- but in a shade of light blue so subtle that I can barely distinguish it from the background white.  Is there any way the contrast could be improved?

Comment: I second this. Higher contrast was quite useful for me, it was much easier and faster to distinguish questions that belong to my favorite tags.

Comment: I second this. As a color blind it is *very* difficult to discern the current color of my favorite tags. The previous color scheme was great.

Comment: As a non-color blind, I can hardly distinguish the color. It is really too subtle now.

Comment: Has there been any confirmation that the devs have seen this request? It was mentioned in @AsafKaragila's color scheme thread (http://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/115/on-the-current-color-scheme-and-why-it-sucks) as an answer but received no response as the thread was mainly concerned with link colours.