# The color of links in comments

Tags: bug, design

In the following image, depicting a piece of a comment on MO.se

[image]

the words «this link» are a link to some URL, yet the styling makes it quite not apparent; the only styling I can see is a `:hover {text-decoration:underline}`, as far as I can see. Could be add some visual reinforcement, so that links are more immediately obvious?

**Update** (after a <del>few months</del> year, to bump this up): I still cannot see links in comments :-(

**New update**, half a year later: I am sure that when the final design for this is finaaally deployed we will all be awed... but can we have good ol' blue&underlined links meanwhile or something?

Comment: Also: http://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/115/on-the-current-color-scheme-and-why-it-sucks

Comment: Mariano: I have noticed your question only after posting mine [here](http://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/552/visibility-of-links-in-comments). Did you observe the same thing as me - that the display was much better for links which you haven't previously visited?

Comment: Now that you bumped this, could you perhaps also respond to the question asked by @MartinSleziak a long time ago, and depending on what the situation is potentially update the post accordingly. It could help in reproducing and thus resolving the matter.

Comment: Dear quid, I am pretty sure that whoever is in charge of the CSS can check than in 2 seconds. :-) In any case, no, I don't see any significant difference.

Comment: Interesting. But it appears to be different for various people; see the link in Martin Sleziak's  comment (not visited links, on main, appear like the 'edit' in you screenshot). For the other point, maybe, maybe not. In any case this is in general not a good way to handle (or do) a bug-report, and even admitting your judgement is good enough to know that in this case all is fine, it sets a bad example.

Comment: @quid: I don't know if it's because I'm color blind or not, but the links on MathOverflow (as well "favorite tags" background) are very difficult to discern from the rest of the text (or questions). In the old MO it **was** slightly different, and the distinction was clearer.

Comment: @AsafKaragila while personally I've no problem to discern *not yet* visited links, I'd certainly be in favor to make it clearer (say via having an underline). What is basically impossible to discern for me are *visited* links, and this is what example illustrate. The issue on which I was commenting is, OP did not care to make clear after having been asked whether they are talking about just the latter or both. This might have had the unfortunate consequence that only the latter gets changed, since for example I, before the disc, was under the impression it is *only* about the visited.

Comment: @quid: Let's test this for a moment. [this is an unvisited link](http://you.didnot.visit.this.site.com). While [this is a visited site](http://mathoverflow.net). **Results:** Well, on a first glance, both are difficult to discern. On a second glance, the unvisited is slightly easier to notice, especially with the visited one in the comment making the distinction slightly clearer. But still both are pretty bad.

Comment: @AsafKaragila we cannot really test this here, meta is different regarding this. On meta I find both alright (only it is a bit hard to distinguish visited and not vistited but then this is not so relevant a distinction, so this is also fine). But since it is only the color I of course can understand why it can be a problem for others. Still, I think the *visited on main* (the illustrated one) is problem for more. Therefore, if the others are also problematic, I think it is important to stress this, so that all get fixed. Else only that one woudl get fixed perhaps.

Comment: @AnnaLear: Maybe it's time for another attempt at fixing this?

Comment: Maybe it would have helped, and it could still help, had you filed a better report. ;-) Have a look at the linked but deleted one to see how one could do such things with details and all.