# Hard to notice links in comments

Tags: discussion, support, feature-request, user-interface

This is a conscious duplicate :D

There are at least two more questions about it ([The color of links in comments](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/320/the-color-of-links-in-comments), [On the current color scheme, and why it sucks](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/115/on-the-current-color-scheme-and-why-it-sucks) - by the way, when trying to share them via the share button I discovered that by some reason both have the same url `https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/320/41291`) but I still decided to post yet another question about it since I could not figure out anything sensible from the existing ones.

So why are links in comments so hard to notice?

Comment: Really? The second question is q number 115 from where I stand.

Comment: @ToddTrimble When I click on "share" there, they give me identical url

Comment: Very strange. Not for me.

Comment: @ToddTrimble After the answer I looked more carefully - sorry, they are not identical, the last part caught my attention and I overlooked the middle part

Answer (score 4):

About the url issue: The last part of the shared url is your own user id. It may have confused you that it is the same for both questions (as it has nothing to do with the questions). The sharing url is of the form `http://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/<question-id>/<user-id>`. The link also works if you drop the last part. I don't know if the user id has any applications beyond [awarding](https://mathoverflow.net/help/badges/54/announcer) [some](https://mathoverflow.net/help/badges/55/booster) [badges](https://mathoverflow.net/help/badges/56/publicist).

I agree that links in questions should become visible.
It should be preferable to give human readable links texts rather than long urls, but the current system encourages the opposite.

Comment: Oh I see now, thanks for the explanation!