# Visited / unvisited links in the questions / answers

Tags: bug, design

I just posted a question and I noticed that *unvisited* links use a color that is difficult to distinguish ... but *visited* links are even harder to  recognize. See the snapshot below from my Firefox 41.0.2 (all default settings).

[image]

Does it look different on other browsers?

Let me know if this is not the right place to ask questions about the appearence of the site (I'll delete the question).

**EDIT:** after reading the comments, it's clear that there is an issue with the css style of visited/unvisited links ... is there a way to signal it to the web designers of mathoverflow?

Comment: Agreed: visited links are practically invisible to me too (also using FF 41.0.2).

Comment: For me univisted links are fine, for visited I agree. See a related question http://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/320/the-color-of-links-in-comments In any case this is the right place to report this.

Comment: If I tilt my computer screen, the visited link looks purple (as I would expect from past experience on this site, and from other sites), but there he purple is very very faint. Unvisited links look blue, again as I would expect.

Comment: I find it almost imposs to distinguish visited links from the rest of the text (on FF, OSX). I think this may have to do with the default css used by MO.

Comment: [I have given up](http://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/1488/change-of-colors) on hoping that anyone pays attention to color schemata problems on SE.