# Buttons (white-on-light grey) look like they are inactive

Tags: bug, user-interface, color-scheme

Many buttons on MO currently have white text on a light grey background, like this:

[image]

(at least on my browser). The text is not very visible, and moreover this color scheme is often used for [inactive/disabled buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SgRvX.png), so it is easy to think subconsciously "I cannot click this button, there must be a reason why it's disabled and I can't perform this action". I find this misleading.

Has the color scheme been changed recently? I don't recall it being this way.

Anyway, I suggest to change the text to black, like in the example below; I think it would be much more visible and less misleading.

[image]

Comment: Maybe ([meta-tag:design]) tag would be suitable here too? (It was used in Asaf Karagila's question on color scheme: [On the current color scheme, and why it sucks](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/115).) I'll just remind that there should be a new theme in the foreseeable future, so probably when that change comes on this site, the developers will communicate more actively with MO users: [Rollout of new network site themes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/312365).

Comment: Forum math.se already got its new theme, and they have white on black for this button.