# Optionally only show "favourite tags" questions

Tags: feature-request

I wonder if it would be possible to optionally only show questions having my "favourite tags" on them. (See also [Questions containing my "favorite tags" are barely distinguishable](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/35/questions-containing-my-favorite-tags-are-barely-distinguishable))

Comment: You can use the search function to only show questions with a given list of tags. E.g.the query http://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/real-analysis+or+linear-algebra which can also be made using the search box in the top right corner of the main mathoverflow page by searching for '[real-analysis] or [linear-algebra]'.

Comment: Poor man's solution (does not render math): Go to your network profile and click on [filtered questions](http://stackexchange.com/filters/). (Filters might be useful for other purposes, too.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one of the things explained in an answer on https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8626/what-can-users-do-to-improve-their-math-se-experience/ as well as a couple of other ways to customize what questions you see.